# time series NDVI - Modis products - GEE

Tags: modis, google-earth-engine

how can I select only good data (Quality informations) from Modis product in Google Earth Engine. 
I tried use this code:

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection ('MODIS/MYD13Q1').select(['NDVI'],['SummaryQA'] == 0).filterDate(ee.Date('2013-01-01'),ee.Date('2015-12-31'))
Map.addLayer(collection)
```

But this does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mask all values where `SummaryQA` is not 0 in every image of your collection. This is done with a `map` in EarthEngine where you define a function to be applied to each image in your collection. You then create a new collection by mapping this function over every image in your old collection. `goodCollection` then only contains observations marked as "Good Data".

```js
var collection = ee.ImageCollection ('MODIS/MYD13Q1')
  .filterDate(ee.Date('2013-01-01'),ee.Date('2015-12-31'))

//function to create mask from SmmaryQA
var maskQA = function(image) {
  return image.updateMask(image.select("SummaryQA").eq(0));
};

var goodCollection = collection.map(maskQA)
```